# Simple transform tolower not working

Tags: c++, tolower

So I've seen a lot of similar issues but none of the answers are fixing my issue. Can someone explain why this code:

```
string LinkedListByName::toLower(string stringToConvert){

return std::transform(stringToConvert.begin(), stringToConvert.end(), stringToConvert.begin(), ::tolower); }
```

is giving me this error:

```
conversion from `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >' to non-scalar type `std::string' requested
```

In the project I'm going to need to convert a lot of strings to lower and boost is NOT an option. I literally copied and pasted this code from previous projects in which it functioned.

Additionally the header file is including the following:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include "Node.h"
namespace model {
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` is a bad idea at nearly all times, but this is certainly the first time I've seen it used three times in a row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should return string, but instead you try to return iterator from std::transform. Change it to this:

```
string LinkedListByName::toLower(string stringToConvert){
    std::transform(stringToConvert.begin(), stringToConvert.end(), stringToConvert.begin(), ::tolower); 
    return stringToConvert;
}
```

Comment: Wow. For some reason I got hung up on the idea that it returned a string, but it doesn't it only acts on it. either way this worked so thanks.

Comment: How many times do you need to copy the `string`? Perhaps it would be better to pass it by reference not return anything.

Comment: "Better" is very subjective term and I doubt we can decide what is better for Nood. Especially when we have so small amount of information.

Comment: @Slava: Hence why I qualified it.

Comment: It may not be better in many situations. For example in current form it can be used as unary transformation function and can be applied on certain algorithms, where variant with reference cannot be, or will be less efficient.